# SWIFT RealmGeoQueries using filter

Tags: swift, realm

I need show results in tableview witch are Unique, sorted from distance from my position.... and THEN use a filter. I am using this framework and function with function ".filter()" but it doesn't seem to work.

```
private func distanceRealm(){
    //get all points closest to me
    let myLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(Double(LocationManager.sharedInstance.latitude)!, Double(LocationManager.sharedInstance.longtitude)!)
    StoredData.sharedInstance.sortedObjectsByDistance = try! Realm().objects(E21.self).filter("Id_prov != ''").filterGeoRadius(myLocation, radius: 50000, sortAscending: true)

    //leave just unique values
    var seenIdProv:[String:Bool] = [:]
    StoredData.sharedInstance.sortedObjectsByDistance = StoredData.sharedInstance.sortedObjectsByDistance.filter {
        seenIdProv.updateValue(false, forKey: $0.Id_prov) ?? true
    }

    print(StoredData.sharedInstance.sortedObjectsByDistance)
}
```

As you can see i have a prob with this.

```
.filter("Id_prov != ''")
```

It gives me err:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "Id_prov != ''"'
```

so how to use filter?

Answer (score 0):

Uh oh.... i found out it using NSPredicate. So the answer is. Put your SQL req as NSPredicate object.

```
var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "Id_prov != ''")


.... .filter(predicate)....
```